# Where to initialize onLongClickListener

Tags: java, android, onclick, adapter, onclicklistener

I am struggling with trying to implement an OnLongClick feature - I can't understand where to add a listener and to define the resulting method.

The implementation i have used uses an adapter - and does not have an onClickListener, but works jsut fine. can anyone suggest where/how to implement OnLongClick listener

I don't need every item in the list to perform different actions - just for anywere on the screen to pick up the long press

```
public class CombChange extends ListActivity {
    @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

setListAdapter(new ListEdit(this, symbols));

@Override
 protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {

  String selectedValue = (String) getListAdapter().getItem(position);
  if (lastPressed.equals(selectedValue) ){
   count++;}
}

public class ListEdit extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
 private final Context context;
 private final String[] values;

 public ListEdit(Context context, String[] values) {
  super(context, R.layout.activity_comb_change, values);
  this.context = context;
  this.values = values;
 }

 @Override
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
  LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
   .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

  View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_comb_change, parent, false);
  TextView textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.label);
  ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.logo);
  textView.setText(values[position]);

  // Change icon based on name
  String s = values[position];

  if (s.equals("a")) {
   imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.a);

return rowView;
}
}
```

Comment: Implement OngestureListener as i posted just 3 mins ago [here][1]
theres a Onlongpressed() method ,thats what u need

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15770887/how-to-handle-swipe-down-gesture-on-an-imageview/15771081#15771081

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is unfortunate that a `ListActivity` does not have a protected `onListItemLongClick()` method similar to the [onListItemClick()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html#onListItemClick%28android.widget.ListView,%20android.view.View,%20int,%20long%29) function.

Instead, you can add `setOnLongClickListener()` to the top-level layout item (or any `View`) in your adapter's `getView()` function.

**Example**:

```
myView.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
        // Do something here.
        return true;
    }
});
```

Warning, the `OnLongClickListener` you put onto your list item may hide exposure to the `onListItemClick()` function you already have working for the list. If this is the case, you will also have to add `setOnClickListener()` to `getView()` and use it instead.

Comment: Your right, no longer picks up non long clicks, however when I try to set an onClickListener eclipse says Cannot instantiate the type View.OnClickListener

Comment: I set long and short click listeners on list items regularly, so there is a small mistake. Here is an example: `myView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
 @Override
 public void onClick(View v) {
  // Do something on short click here.
 }
});`  Make sure you are importing the right kind of OnClickListener: `import android.view.View.OnClickListener;`

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
@Override
 protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {

v.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                String selectedValue = (String) getListAdapter().getItem(position);
                if (lastPressed.equals(selectedValue) ){
                count++;}

                return false;
            }
        });


}
```

Answer (score 0):

in your getView you can say

```
rowview.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View arg0) {
                //Do your stuff here
                return false;
            }
        });
```